# How to condensed a data frame based on nearest matching times in R

Tags: r, time, match, datetime-format

I have a data frame that currently contains two ‘time’ columns in HH:MM:SS format. I would like to condense this data frame so that I only have one row for each unique ‘id’ value. I would like to keep the row for each unique ‘id’ value which has a ‘time1’ value that is the nearest match to the ‘time2’ value. However, 'time1' needs to be greater than ‘time2’.

Here is a simple example:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), count = c(23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L), time1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("00:13:00", 
"01:13:00", "07:18:00", "18:14:00"), class = "factor"), time2 = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("00:00:00", 
"06:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00"), class = "factor"), afn = c(3.36, 
0.63, 1.77, 3.89, 3.36, 0.63, 1.77, 3.89, 3.36, 0.63, 1.77, 3.89, 
3.36, 0.63, 1.77, 3.89), dfn = c(201.67, 157.27, 103.55, 191.41, 
201.67, 157.27, 103.55, 191.41, 201.67, 157.27, 103.55, 191.41, 
201.67, 157.27, 103.55, 191.41)), .Names = c("id", "count", "time1", 
"time2", "afn", "dfn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

> df
   id count    time1    time2  afn    dfn
1   1    23 00:13:00 18:00:00 3.36 201.67
2   1    23 00:13:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
3   1    23 00:13:00 06:00:00 1.77 103.55
4   1    23 00:13:00 12:00:00 3.89 191.41
5   2    45 01:13:00 18:00:00 3.36 201.67
6   2    45 01:13:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
7   2    45 01:13:00 06:00:00 1.77 103.55
8   2    45 01:13:00 12:00:00 3.89 191.41
9   3    67 18:14:00 18:00:00 3.36 201.67
10  3    67 18:14:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
11  3    67 18:14:00 06:00:00 1.77 103.55
12  3    67 18:14:00 12:00:00 3.89 191.41
13  4    88 07:18:00 18:00:00 3.36 201.67
14  4    88 07:18:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
15  4    88 07:18:00 06:00:00 1.77 103.55
16  4    88 07:18:00 12:00:00 3.89 191.41
```

I would like to end up with this matrix in the above case:

```
id  count   time1       time2       afn     dfn
1   23      00:13:00    00:00:00    0.63    157.27
2   45      01:13:00    00:00:00    0.63    157.27
3   67      18:14:00    18:00:00    3.36    201.67
4   88      07:18:00    06:00:00    1.77    103.55
```

I have used the ddply() function to condense data frames in the past, but not with an incorporated matching rule. I have to apply this is a data frame with lots of columns (many more than the simple example given here) so any suggestions about how to do this would be brilliant. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: I would like to point out that the ordering suggests that the `18:00:00` comes before `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few solutions.

**1) ave** This uses chron `times` as well as `subset` and `ave` from the base of R:

```
library(chron)

delta <- as.vector(times(df$time1) - times(df$time2))
df2 <- subset(df, delta > 0)
df2[ave(delta, df2$id, FUN = function(delta) delta == min(delta)) == 1, ]
```

**2) dplyr** This uses chron `times` and the dplyr package:

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr) 

df %.% 
   mutate(delta = as.vector(times(time1) - times(time2))) %.% 
   filter(delta > 0) %.% 
   group_by(id) %.% 
   filter(delta == min(delta)) %.% 
   select(- delta)
```

**3) sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *, min(strftime('%s', time1) - strftime('%s', time2)) delta
  from (select * from df where strftime('%s', time1) > strftime('%s', time2))
  group by id")[seq_along(df)]
```

or perhaps this variation where we calculate `delta` in R and then use `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
library(chron)

df2 = transform(df, delta = as.vector(times(time1) - times(time2)))

sqldf("select *, min(delta) delta
  from (select * from df2 where delta > 0)
  group by id")[-ncol(df2)]
```

**4) data.table**

```
library(data.table)
library(chron)

DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, delta := times(time1) - times(time2)
 ][delta > 0
 ][, .SD[delta == min(delta)], by = id
 ][, seq_along(df), with = FALSE]
```

*ADDED* additional solutions.  Corrected `library` and `subset` statements.  Minor improvements.

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck: Many thanks for the many different options. dplyr is great! just a small thing: should it read `df2 <- subset(df, delta > 0)` rather the `subset(df2…)` on code line 3? Many thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, have fixed it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with the powerful `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

(df %.%
   mutate(timeDiff = as.integer(strptime(time1, "%X") - strptime(time2, "%X")),
          posDiff = timeDiff >= 0) %.%
   filter(posDiff) %.%
   group_by(id) %.%
   filter(min(timeDiff) == timeDiff))[names(df)]

#   id count    time1    time2  afn    dfn
# 1  1    23 00:13:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
# 2  2    45 01:13:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
# 3  3    67 18:14:00 18:00:00 3.36 201.67
# 4  4    88 07:18:00 06:00:00 1.77 103.55
```

Comment: @ Sven: also many thanks for the dplyr suggestion. I will have to look more into this package.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `ddply` and `merge`. (Assuming that the "nearest match times" are the minimum absolute values of the `difftime`s)

```
t1 <- strptime(df$time1, "%H:%M:%S")
t2 <- strptime(df$time2, "%H:%M:%S")
df$min.diff <- abs(as.numeric(difftime(t1, t2, units='mins')))

d1 <- ddply(df, .(id), summarize, min.diff = min(min.diff))

> merge(df, d1, by = c("id", "min.diff"))
  id min.diff count    time1    time2  afn    dfn
1  1       13    23 00:13:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
2  2       73    45 01:13:00 00:00:00 0.63 157.27
3  3       14    67 18:14:00 18:00:00 3.36 201.67
4  4       78    88 07:18:00 06:00:00 1.77 103.55
```

Comment: @ Julien: Thanks for the answer. Is there supposed to be an extra line in the code where you define `datas`?

Comment: Oh no sorry it's "df" not "datas" indeed.

Comment: Note that strptime output includes today's date so if by chance t1 was set just before midnight and then t2 set just after midnight then t1 and t2 would have different dates whereas if they are run on the same day the would have the same date.  Of course this is extremely unlikely but it is possible.